# Angular Router, dynamic argument not leting above routes work

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router, angular6, angular2-routing

im trying to make a page that expect and argument but if i put it bellow other route (eg:login) it does not open anymore instead it opens the dynamic route, and the page its needed to be: www.website/dynamic-name
what could be causing the error?

App routing

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule, PreloadAllModules } from '@angular/router';
import { HomeComponent } from './pages/home/home.component';
...

const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', redirectTo: '/home', pathMatch: 'full'},
  { path: 'home', component: HomeComponent },
  { path:'login', component: LoginComponent },//--> this one does not open login page, but instead open the below "PharmacyDetailsComponent "
  { path: ':name', component: PharmacyDetailsComponent } , //--> this one opens
```

but login page does not open
];

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forRoot(routes, { preloadingStrategy: PreloadAllModules, enableTracing: false,  useHash: true })
  ],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

calling the page

```
goToSupplierDetail(supplierName: string) {
        this.router.navigate([`${supplierName}`],{...});
 }
```

Comment: It works? @Kevin Dias

Answer (score 1):

I think you are trying to navigate to the dynamic page on other pages such as home or login. So you should use the absolute path. Add `/` before the route path.

```
this.router.navigate([`/${supplierName}`]);
```

Let me know if it works.
Otherwise, you can use relative path.

```
...
constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) {}
...
this.router.navigate([`../${supplierName}`], { relativeTo: this.route });
```

Comment: it does work but now if i click to go to login route it still on the same page

Comment: If it does not work, turn off the dev env and try `ng serve` again.

Comment: The route order you made is correct. Dynamic paths should be underneath the static ones so it does not interrupt the static ones.

Comment: yea its a wierd bug, if i click login page it goes to the dynamic route, but if go to dynamic route it self it works, but the url change but not the component

Comment: did you try restarting the dev env?

Comment: but not working yet? could you share your PharmacyDetailsComponent with me?

Comment: its an empty page i generated with angular cli the default one

Comment: weird. did you call `goToSupplierDetail` on a tag? could it be that you wrote it `<a href="" (click)="goToSupplierDetail('blabla')"></a>`?

Comment: no ,b i think i isolated the bug if i do this
 `{ path:'login', component: LoginComponent }, --> this one load the PharmacyDetailsComponent  data but the url change
 { path: ':name', component: PharmacyDetailsComponent }`